# Oracle Pooling DataSource - Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler

Tags: java, spring, oracle, jdbc, oracle11g

I would like to implement Oracle Pooling DataSource using Spring as described here:
http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jdbc/docs/current/reference/html/orcl.datasource.html

However, I am getting this problem:

```
Configuration problem: Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler for XML schema namespace [http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/orcl]
Offending resource: class path resource [applicationContext.xml]
```

In my understanding, this problem is caused because Spring is not able to locate Oracle JDBC Driver. However, the driver is in my classpath; so, I don't know what could be causing this problem.

applicationContext.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
     xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
     xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
     xmlns:orcl="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/orcl"
     xsi:schemaLocation="
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-3.0.xsd
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/orcl http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/orcl/spring-data-orcl-1.0.xsd">

<orcl:pooling-datasource
    id="dataSource"
    url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@//abc.ca:1527/abc_default.abc.ca"
    username="abc"
    password="abc"/>
```

pom.xml

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
        <version>11.2.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.retry</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-retry</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Did you ever get to the bottom of this? I'm facing the same issue.

Comment: I gave up on this. I had too much problems with Oracle Pooling Datasource; so, I moved to C3P0 as described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33553532/configure-c3p0-in-spring-application-context-intsql-and-timezone/33635526#33635526

Answer (score 3):

Seems there is missing dependency to spring-data-oracle. Try this:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-data-oracle</artifactId>
  <version>1.2.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

JDBC drivers will not be accessible on the maven repository.  You will need to download JDBC drivers manually from [OTN](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/jdbc/index-091264.html)

Install this on Maven using the following command.

mvn install:install-file 
      -Dfile=/lib/12102/ojdbc7.jar 
      -DgroupId=com.oracle 
      -DartifactId=ojdbc7 
      -Dversion=12.1.0.1 
      -Dpackaging=jar 
      -DgeneratePom=true

You can include the dependency in pom.xml as shown.

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
      <artifactId>ojdbc7</artifactId>
      <version>12.1.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: JDBC Driver is already installed in my repository using similar approach. However, this brings me to a new question. I am second guessing if I have downloaded the correct driver. Will, re-download and test again. Thanks