# Configure c3p0 in spring application context (intSQL and timezone)

Tags: spring, c3p0, spring-mybatis

How to configure c3p0 in spring application context?

I am running mybatis + spring + c3p0 + Oracle 11g.

c3p0 documentation for [extensions](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#extensions) says:

> extensions Default: an empty java.util.Map A java.util.Map (raw type)
>   containing the values of any user-defined configuration extensions
>   defined for this DataSource.

c3p0 documentation for [user extensions to configurations](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#user_extensions_to_configurations) says:

> ```
> <extensions>
>   <property name="initSql">SET SCHEMA 'foo'</property>
>   <property name="timezone">PDT</property>
> </extensions>
> ```

Therefore, I configured my spring application context as:

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClass" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" />
    <property name="jdbcUrl" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@//databasehost:1527/servicename" />
    <property name="user" ref="database.user" />
    <property name="password" ref="database.password" />
    <property name="extensions">
        <map>
            <entry key="initSql" value="ALTER SESSION SET CURRENT_SCHEMA = MY_SCHEMA" />
            <entry key="timezone" value="UTC" />
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>
```

However nothing happens, it doesn't throw error but doesn't behave as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you did in your answer is not enough to make it work.

If you investigate your mysql log you will see that the `timezone` setting never takes effect for example (there will be no "set time_zone..." statement executing ever).

The only thing that takes effect in your answer is: `preferredTestQuery` which you have set to be `alter session set current_schema=MY_SCHEMA`.

This means that every **Checkin (which happens before almost every query you execute - i.e TOO MUCH)** will also call `alter session set current_schema=MY_SCHEMA` which is a very bad performance practice...

If you want to execute some SQL when the connection is aquired, you need to use a `ConnectionCustomizer` in combination with the `extensions` Map you have created. (you can see it written in their documentation [here](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#user_extensions_to_configurations))

Example:

```
public class ExampleConnectionCustomizer extends AbstractConnectionCustomizer {
    public ExampleConnectionCustomizer () {
    }

    private String getInitSql(String parentDataSourceIdentityToken) {
        return (String)this.extensionsForToken(parentDataSourceIdentityToken).get("initSql");
    }

    public void onAcquire(Connection c, String pdsIdt) {
        String initSql = this.getInitSql(parentDataSourceIdentityToken);
        if(initSql != null) {
            Statement stmt = null;
            try {
                stmt = c.createStatement();
                stmt.executeUpdate(initSql);
            } finally {
                if(stmt != null) {
                    stmt.close();
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    ....The rest of your properties...
    <property name="preferredTestQuery" value="SELECT 1" /> <!--Much more efficient-->
    <property name="connectionCustomizerClassName" value="yourpackage.ExampleConnectionCustomizer" />
    <!-- extensions -->         
    <property name="extensions">
        <map>
            <entry key="initSql" value="alter session set current_schema=MY_SCHEMA" />
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: That is great. thank you very much for your help. Just for reference, here is the javadocs for InitSqlConnectionCustomizer containing similar feature: https://github.com/swaldman/c3p0/blob/9f97c814aef31b2997d6ecfad1e3875c6136317b/src/java/com/mchange/v2/c3p0/example/InitSqlConnectionCustomizer.java

Answer (score -1):

**EDIT**: Not a good idea. Better to follow  Shay Elkayam's approach

---

After lots of digging I came up with this fully working configuration:

```
<!--
    DataSource with connection polling
    For more details, see: http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/
 -->
<bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClass" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" />
    <property name="jdbcUrl" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@//hostaname:1527/servicename" />
    <property name="user" value="user" />
    <property name="password" value="password" />
    <!-- Other DataSource Configuration -->
    <property name="numHelperThreads" value="10" />
    <property name="maxAdministrativeTaskTime" value="10000" />
    <!-- pool sizing -->
    <property name="initialPoolSize" value="3" />
    <property name="minPoolSize" value="10" />
    <property name="maxPoolSize" value="35" />
    <property name="acquireIncrement" value="3" />
    <property name="maxStatements" value="0" />
    <!-- retries -->
    <property name="acquireRetryAttempts" value="30" />
    <property name="acquireRetryDelay" value="1000" /> <!-- 1s -->
    <property name="breakAfterAcquireFailure" value="false" />
    <!-- refreshing connections -->
    <property name="maxIdleTime" value="180" /> <!-- 3min -->
    <property name="maxConnectionAge" value="300" />
    <!-- timeouts and testing -->
    <property name="checkoutTimeout" value="5000" /> <!-- 5s -->
    <property name="idleConnectionTestPeriod" value="60" /> <!-- 60s -->
    <property name="testConnectionOnCheckout" value="true" />
    <property name="testConnectionOnCheckin" value="true" />
    <property name="preferredTestQuery" value="alter session set current_schema=MY_SCHEMA" />
    <!-- extensions -->         
    <property name="extensions">
        <map>
            <entry key="timezone" value="UTC" />
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>
```